# Conflicting Jquery, can't get both plugins to work together

Tags: jquery, html

I need help understanding how to use two jquery plugins on the same page.
I am trying to use eastslider on the bottom and revolutionary plugin on the top.

When i go into my index and delete
`script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script`

from line 306 
my top slider starts working and my bottom project slider stops working.

the examples is on `http://trulyamped.com/test/index.html`   please let me know how to make them stop conflicting.

Comment: Have you checked which versions of jquery these plugins support?

Comment: i would not know where to look

Comment: The websites of the plugins you are using would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `jQuery.noConflict();` to avoid conflicts.
[Example from jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries&redirect=no)

Comment: hello? do you know where it goes?

Comment: you can add in the start of the file, right after the lines where you included the jQuery files and than change rest of the code accordingly.